A group of kids help a blind man drive a vehicle
This is an English speaking film that I saw in the 90s.
The main protagonist is a blind man that has some abilities (maybe he can sense people too well).
At one moment, he befriends a group of kids who help him towards his motives (Which I don't recall).
One of the scenes I remember is him driving a vehicle although he is blind. He gets directions from the kids riding with him. Maybe they are chasing someone or running away from someone.
Anyways, at a moment, they get excited (because they have evaded the enemy) and they forget to give directions to the blind man still driving the vehicle. He asks something like: what should I do now?
At which they scream: stop, and he slams the brakes as best as he can and manages to stop the vehicle within inches from the wall/other vehicle/obstacle. 
In one other scene, we see the blind man giving a plastic toy (a rhino) to someone (maybe an old friend), as a gift with some value beyond the cheap toy's value. The guy who receives the gift, later throws it away. After the climax of the film, we see the toy dropping down from a high place, but the blind man catches it before it is lost (in the river? can't remember).

Blind Fury from 1989 with Rutger Hauer, though I'm pretty sure it's a toy dinosaur.

Nick Parker was a Vietnam vet who was blinded during the war. He was found by one of the local tribes, who taught him to enhance his remaining senses and to expertly wield a sword. On his return to the United States, he goes to visit an old Army buddy, Frank Devereaux, but discovers that he and his wife are divorced, and Frank no longer lives there. What they don't know is that Devereaux was playing in a crooked casino in Vegas, and accumulated a large debt. The casino boss is willing to forgive his debt if he does something for him: Devereaux is a chemist, and they want him to make designer drugs. In order to make sure he does it, they try to kidnap his son. But Nick is there, and Nick saves the boy. Thus begins a road trip to Vegas to protect the boy and save his friend, with the boss' henchmen in pursuit. 

It includes the scene you've described (the gang evades the bad guys with Nick at the wheel, celebrates it and forget to give him instructions then yell "Stop!" and he stops an inch from a wall). Here's the trailer:



